# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant' not found

Tags: php, namespaces, bing

I am trying to install BingAds API and I keep getting the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant' not found

I checked the composer file it looks OK.

```
{
    "name": "microsoft/bingads",
    "description": "This project provides a set of PHP client libraries that make it easy to access Bing Ads service APIs.",
    "keywords": [ "php", "bingads", "bing ads", "sdk" ],
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "type": "library",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.17",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Microsoft\\BingAds\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Microsoft",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK/graphs/contributors"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, the OAuth2Callback.php files look fine I am calling the namespace on the header as `use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant;` and later it calls the class `OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant()` on the line that gives the error.

The file structure is like:

```
- BingAds-PHP-SDK-master
- - OAuth2Callback.php
- - WebAuthHelper.php
- - composer.json
- - composer.lock
- - /samples
- - /src
- - /vendor
```

Does anybody have any clues? I am new with namespaces, not completely sure how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more details about OAuth2Callback.php? Have you tried this [web app walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/walkthrough-web-application-php?view=bingads-12)? If you are running this locally in a console then I suggest starting with [this console walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/walkthrough-desktop-application-php?view=bingads-12).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I downloaded V13 source code from https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK, because the command "composer require microsoft/bingads" from the instruction only sending me the V12 not V13.

I got same error: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant' not found.

Compared to the composer.json.

in V13:

"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Microsoft\BingAds\": "/src/"
        }
    },

and in v12:

"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Microsoft\BingAds\": "src/"
        }
    },

after updated the path from "/src/" to "src/", ran "composer update" and it works.